# CodeIgniter CSRF protection and page caching

Tags: codeigniter, caching, csrf

I've searched around but couldn't find anything about this. Am I the only one who have experienced that CSRF protection in CodeIgniter doesn't work with page caching?

What do I have:

A webpage which will be cached trough this line:

```
$this->output->cache( 120 );
```

In the Javascript on that page I've got a Ajax call where the data contains the CSRF token too. Everything works fine when caching is disabled or when I disable CSRF protection.

Does somebody know a workaround or something so I can have caching and CSRF protection enabled?

Thanks!

Comment: What *exactly* doesn't work properly when CSRF is paired with AJAX *and* page caching? Can you show more code (like your ajax call) and how you've generated the form (I assume using `form_open()`)?

Comment: Page caching will cache the csrf token in the form too so it won't be refreshed cases that csrf fails.

Comment: I ask because I would have assumed `form_open()` would handle that for you, in a similar way to benchmarks (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/caching.html).

Comment: Yes, I'm using form_open(), but CodeIgniter doesn't handle it the same as the benchmarks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm somewhat surprised that `form_open()` doesn't handle that for you, in a similar way that benchmarking functions' output aren't cached.

Here are two possible workarounds.

#### Use the caching driver (!= output->cache())

Instead of using Output class caching, which caches a *completely rendered page*, you could employ the [caching driver's key-value cache](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/caching.html#file) to save rendered *portions of your page*.

If the form containing this problematic CSRF token is complex and contains a lot of dynamic content from an external  data source, cache those database results (either with the caching driver or by enabling [database result caching](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/caching.html)) and feed the cached values into a dynamic form.

Warning about file-based cache from the manual:

> Unlike caching from the Output Class, the driver file-based caching
>   allows for pieces of view files to be cached. Use this with care, and
>   make sure to benchmark your application, as a point can come where
>   disk I/O will negate positive gains by caching.

Of course, if you have access to memcached or APC, use that instead.

Disable output caching for that page and profile.

#### Intercepting the output cache (fully-rendered page) and replacing the CSRF token value

I came across an interesting solution on [Caching forms with CSRF tokens](http://symfony-blog.driebit.nl/2012/03/caching-forms-with-csrf-tokens/) (in Symfony). To paraphrase the original author:

1. Before setting the cached response, find and replace CSRF tokens.
2. Store the position of the tokens with the response (so it gets cached as well).
3. Before returning a response from the cache inject fresh CSRF tokens.

In CodeIgniter, intercepting the cache [seems to require](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13772485/114900) use of [the `pre_system` hook-point](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html), though in your case, you may be able to use `cache_override`. Take a look [at this excellent article](http://www.beheist.com/index.php/en/blog/csrf-protection-in-codeigniter-2-0-a-closer-look) on the way in which CodeIgniter implements CRSF tokens for inspiration. I don't think it would be trivial to implement, though.

#### Don't cache that page and don't worry about it

This is obviously the simplest solution. Test it. Depending on your page complexity, the negative performance impact of not caching that subset of pages may well outweigh the pain of implementing either of the above two solutions. (Since we don't know what your views or controller look like, whether or not this is an acceptable solution in your case isn't immediately obvious). If it's an [isolated login form in an SPA](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171418/why-make-the-login-page-to-a-single-page-application-a-separate-page/171421#171421), you can probbaly get away with it.

Comment: Really helpful answer! I'll dig into it and let you know my choice and solution.

Comment: @Roy Thanks! Researching this answer, I've found that this is actually a somewhat poorly-covered topic. It prompted me to make an example CI site to experiment with different caching methods (blog + github when it's done). Do let us know what you decide, too!

Comment: I think the best solution is extending the Output class. If you look here: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/master/system/core/Output.php#L366 you'll find the elapsed time and memory usage. By adding after this some kind of search and replace like: Search for a hidden input with the name equal to `$CI->security->get_csrf_token_name()` and replace the value with `$CI->security->get_csrf_hash()`. That will do the trick!

Comment: Well done, @Roy! Thanks for coming back and posting your findings.

Comment: Haven't implemented it yet but I think that's the best solution. Meanwhile I've posted this as an issue but they don't see it as one: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/2325. When I've implemented it I'll post the code!

Comment: Not a single link in this answer is working.

Comment: @Awaisfiaz So, this answer is nearly a decade old and applies to an antique version of CI. Also, the [Github issue](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/2325), whose link does work, categorically states what the root problem was in the end. Nevertheless, perhaps these will be useful https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf and https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/caching.html :)